# I want to read this JSON lines but because it start with JSONObject and JsonArray

Tags: android

I just need to save first **Table:[]** rows like to show in table-layout in Android Studio (get string) values from the below answer. Please give any other way to get this details from this below code, I given in http request

```
{
    "Result": {
        "resultsrow": [
            {
                "RowError": "",
                "RowState": 2,
                "Table": [
                    {
                        "refno": "09127178888",
                        "name": "S Santhosh kumar",
                        "address": "qwerty",
                        "mobile": 123456789,

                    },
                    {
                        "refno": "0912717999999",
                        "name": "ggg",
                        "address": "gggttr54",
                        "mobile": 2134567890,

                    }
                ],
                "ItemArray": [
                    "091271788888",
                    "S Santhosh kumar",
                    "qwerty1",
                    1234567890,

                ],
                "HasErrors": false
            },
            {
                "RowError": "",
                "RowState": 2,
                "Table": [
                    {
                        "refno": "091271788888",
                        "name": "S Santhosh kumar",
                        "address": "qwerty",
                        "mobile": 1234567890,

                    },
                    {
                        "refno": "091271799999",
                        "name": "ggg",
                        "address": "gggttr54, ",
                        "mobile": 2134567890,

                    }
                ],
                "ItemArray": [
                    "0912717999999",
                    "ggg",
                    "gggttr54, ",
                    2134567890,

                ],
                "HasErrors": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "Message": "",
    "Success": true
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this , this will work for you

```
   try {
        JSONObject j= new JSONObject(YourJsonString);
        JSONObject result= (JSONObject) j.get("Result");
        JSONArray resultsrowArray=result.getJSONArray("resultsrow");
        for (int i = 0; i < resultsrowArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject arrayObject= resultsrowArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String RowError=arrayObject.getString("RowError");
            int RowState=arrayObject.getInt("RowState");
            JSONArray ItemArray=arrayObject.getJSONArray("ItemArray");
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < ItemArray.length(); i1++) {
                String item1= ItemArray.getString(i1);


            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how to get  "ItemArray":[] only?

Comment: please check my answer now

Comment: All the best @SanThoShKumar

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Result": {
        "resultsrow": [
            {
                "RowError": "",
                "RowState": 2,
                "Table": [
                    {
                        "refno": "09127178888",
                        "name": "S Santhosh kumar",
                        "address": "qwerty",
                        "mobile": 123456789,

                    },
                    {
                        "refno": "0912717999999",
                    "name": "ggg",
                    "address": "gggttr54",
                    "mobile": 2134567890,

                }
            ],
            "ItemArray": [
                "091271788888",
                "S Santhosh kumar",
                "qwerty1",
                1234567890, // here is the problem.

            ],
            "HasErrors": false
        },
        {
            "RowError": "",
            "RowState": 2,
            "Table": [
                {
                    "refno": "091271788888",
                    "name": "S Santhosh kumar",
                    "address": "qwerty",
                    "mobile": 1234567890,

                },
                {
                    "refno": "091271799999",
                    "name": "ggg",
                    "address": "gggttr54, ",
                    "mobile": 2134567890, 

                }
            ],
            "ItemArray": [
                "0912717999999",
                "ggg",
                "gggttr54, ",
                2134567890, // here is the problem.

            ],
            "HasErrors": false
        }
    ]
},
"Message": "",
"Success": true
}
```

this [] brackets arrays must be a string array. you cannot create items with multiple types of arrays.  you can change the int types into strings as follows.

```
{
    "Result": {
        "resultsrow": [
            {
                "RowError": "",
                "RowState": 2,
                "Table": [
                    {
                        "refno": "09127178888",
                        "name": "S Santhosh kumar",
                        "address": "qwerty",
                        "mobile": 123456789,

                    },
                    {
                        "refno": "0912717999999",
                    "name": "ggg",
                    "address": "gggttr54",
                    "mobile": 2134567890,

                }
            ],
            "ItemArray": [
                "091271788888",
                "S Santhosh kumar",
                "qwerty1",
                "1234567890", // *******

            ],
            "HasErrors": false
        },
        {
            "RowError": "",
            "RowState": 2,
            "Table": [
                {
                    "refno": "091271788888",
                    "name": "S Santhosh kumar",
                    "address": "qwerty",
                    "mobile": 1234567890,

                },
                {
                    "refno": "091271799999",
                    "name": "ggg",
                    "address": "gggttr54, ",
                    "mobile": 2134567890, 

                }
            ],
            "ItemArray": [
                "0912717999999",
                "ggg",
                "gggttr54, ",
                "2134567890", // ***********

            ],
            "HasErrors": false
        }
    ]
},
"Message": "",
"Success": true
}
```